# How do I get Oracle 11g to install on Vista when it gives an error about the listener port?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, windows-vista

I'm trying to do an install of Oracle 11g.R2 taking the defaults, but the installers keeps generating and error message when trying to setup the listener. If I have the installer just install the software and I then try to create the listener, the listener configuration keeps saying that the port is in use. I don't see port 1521 in netstat and I've tried other ports.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out the exact reason but it seems that some of the software was crashing. I was using the 32bit version of Oracle on Windows Vista (64bit). After seeing a note in the documentation about limited support for this setup, I downloaded the 64bit version of Oracle 11gR2 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

And just to make sure, you are using netstat -a for all ports, right?

Try a different port. Also, do you have a firewall setup and have you allowed that port to be passed through?